# Change Maya 2016 Tumble Tool Axis

Tags: maya

Older versions of Maya will tumble around the Y axis with horizontal movement, that is alt+lmb left and right drag. Maya 2016 now tumbles around the Z axis with horizontal movement. Is there are way to change this back to the old style tumble?

Answer (score 1):

Some how the "World Coordinate System" was set to Z up. Setting the Up axis to Y under Preferences->Settings will restore the familiar tumble.
[Settings Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ8g5.png)